# Algorítmo para plano de corte

Tags: algoritmo, geometria

Não sei se esse é o melhor local para fazer esta pergunta, mas eu procurei muito na internet por algum algorítmo para plano de corte - que informando as dimensões das peças ele mostra a melhor arranjo para que se disperdice o mínimo possível.

Alguém conhece algum algorítmo próximo dessa realidade?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu já vi um sistema desses funcionando em uma marcenaria, então com certeza existe já pronto. Você já fez alguma busca sobre priorização por tamanho? Acho que pode ser um bom ponto de partida.

Comment: Eu encontrei esse material: http://www.dct.ufms.br/~eah/pli/planos-de-corte-4p.pdf - extremamente acadêmico e pouco didático

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O nome desse tipo de algoritmo em inglês é *Bin Packing*, uma variante do [problema da mochila](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila).

Uma árvore binária é utilizada para selecionar, em vários passes, a melhor distribuição (*optimal distribution*) de um conteúdo por ordem  e percentual de utilização de superfície.

Uma excelente implementação do algoritmo pode ser encontrada aqui:
http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/

Exemplo de uso:
http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/example/

Eu tomei a liberdade de testar as áreas da sua imagem de exemplo na demo do algoritmo. Este é o resultado (eu dividi as dimensões por 10 e arredondei os valores):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ótimo ponto de partida! Obrigado