# Cálculo de frete

Tags: php, mysql, api, web-service

Estou tentando elaborar um sistema de frete para uma empresa mas estou com um problema. Assim,segue-se:

- *o frete em si é calculado pelo sistema dos Correios que acesso por meio de uma API*;
- *já fiz tudo o que consta no site dos Correios para realizar as consultas para cálculo de frete*;

Para a API dos Correios, se fazem necessários a altura, a largura, o peso e o comprimento do produto. Estes valores, por sua vez, são obtidos do banco de dados do cliente de acordo com o produto a que se deseja calcular o frete. Como os produtos são personalizados, se a quantidade de produtos passar de uma determinada quantidade - por exemplo, 50 - o sistema que fiz acaba multiplicando os valores por 2.

Preciso que o sistema obtenha o maior valor de comprimento e de largura e some a altura e o peso. Preciso que esse cálculo seja feito para, por exemplo, colocar uma caixa em cima da outra e não lado a lado pois as caixas menores sempre serão colocadas, no envio, em cima das maiores. Evita prejuízos para o cliente e fornecedor.

Não consigo pensar em uma maneira de resolver este problema. Alguma ideia?

Comment: eu editei sua pergunta para tornar o texto mais legível. De qualquer modo, você precisa mostrar seu código para que alguém consiga te ajudar - a parte relevante à dúvida. E mesmo assim, as dúvidas aqui no SO deveriam ser mais direcionadas à perspectiva técnica e aprendizado do que a algo do tipo 'faça para mim' - talvez alguém sinalize a sua pergunta (suponho).

Comment: Entao leonardo, apesar da sua explicaçao... ela gera duvidas... esse material sera realmente enviado pelo o correio Ou é um outro tipo de frete? Se for pelo correio que eu saiba existe limite maximo de espaço para enviar em uma caixa certo? Para otimizar esse espaço vc tem  que calcular a area dele junto com a area de cada produto...

Comment: o titulo está certo ? "frete de frete" ?

Comment: O seu problema não é trivial. Quando você define um espaço delimitador fixo (o tamanho da caixa/limite de espaço mencionado pelo colega @AndreiCoelho), o problema é conhecido popularmente como "Problema do Carregamento de Paletes". Se você procurar por esse termo, vai achar várias propostas de abordagem. Por exemplo: http://www.lac.inpe.br/~lorena/glaydston/lagclus-pallet.pdf Talvez alguma delas lhe sirva. Infelizmente é só até ai que eu consigo ajudar.

Comment: Outro link que pode ser útil: http://www.scielo.br/pdf/pope/v23n2/a07v23n2. Ele não envolve sobreposição, mas talvez você consiga fazer em várias execuções (por camadas) e priorizar as caixas maiores nas primeiras execuções (camadas inferiores).

Comment: Mas, eu acho que a abordagem mais fácil pra você talvez seja "estimar" de maneira mais grosseira (com maior erro) o volume necessário simplesmente somando os volumes das caixas e tentando acomodá-las em uma caixa de tamanho pré-definido. Algo como o [problema da mochila](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27767/algor%C3%ADtmo-para-plano-de-corte/27778#27778) (essa [outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7107/maximizar-solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-sublistas-atendendo-limite/7408#7408) também pode ser útil).

Comment: Gostei das suas dicas @LuizVieira... pode me ajudar no futuro também